# Cannot access mysql on VPS server from remote terminal

Tags: mysql, joomla, root

There is configured site on Joomla on VPS server. Joomla works fine. There is a data about mysql user/password(NOT ROOT) in configuration.php file, but I cannot access to mysql or phpmyadmin with this data from remote terminal. Even a php file "test.php" cannot access to database, when I run mydomen/test.php.

Comment: First of all, check the configuration of your MySQL server, and make sure it allows remote connections.